# Erro ao inserir dados na tabela!

Tags: php, mysql

No sistema de cadastro de alunos tem este esquema lógico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De que forma posso inserir os dados do aluno correto ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**SQL**

```
-- Geração de Modelo físico
-- Sql ANSI 2003 - brModelo.



CREATE TABLE Aluno (
idaluno varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
nomeAluno varchar(50),
matricula varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Endereco (
idendereco varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
nomerua varchar(50),
cidade varchar(50),
idaluno varchar(50),
FOREIGN KEY(idaluno) REFERENCES Aluno (idaluno)
);

CREATE TABLE Turma (
idturma varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
codturma varchar(50),
nomeprofessor varchar(50),
quantidadealunos int,
idaluno varchar(50),
FOREIGN KEY(idaluno) REFERENCES Aluno (idaluno)
);
```

**Codigo PHP**

```
<?php

        $NOME           ="";
        $MATRICULA      ="";
        $NOMERUA        ="";
        $CIDADE         ="";
        $CODTURMA       ="";
        $NOMEPROFESSOR  ="";
        #QUANTIDADE     ="";

     $query = "INSERT INTO aluno('NOME','MATRICULA') VALUES($NOME,$MATRICULA)";

    ?>
```

Comment: Qual é o erro ?

Comment: Não esta sendo inserido corretamente os dados

Comment: A duvida esta como inserir o nome do aluno e ao mesmo tempo inserir os dados na tabelas relacionadas: Endereço e Turma ???

Comment: Uma pergunta, porque da tag *Python* ? Esta utilizando *PHP* e *Python* ?

Comment: O sistema esta em php.

Comment: Devo fazer a query insert dupla ??

Comment: devo fazer query1(inserti tabela1: aluno) e query2 (insert tabela2: endereco  ) e query3(tabela3:turma)

Comment: Veja esse tutorial: [Relacionamento de Tabelas no MySQL](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/relacionamento-de-tabelas-no-mysql)

Comment: Existe uma forma em inserir dados em, mais de uma tabela ao mesmo tempo ?

Comment: MySQL ou PostGreSQL?

Comment: o banco de dados é MySql

Comment: Eu posso usar INNER JOIN no insert ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente tomei a liberdade de alterar a sua estrutura, como o campo `idaluno` é `AUTO INCREMENTO` acredito que seja melhor trabalhar com o tipo numérico, então mudei para `int`:

```
CREATE TABLE Aluno (
  idaluno int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nomeAluno varchar(50),
  matricula varchar(50)
);

CREATE TABLE Endereco (
  idendereco int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nomerua varchar(50),
  cidade varchar(50),
  idaluno int,
  FOREIGN KEY(idaluno) REFERENCES Aluno (idaluno)
);

CREATE TABLE Turma (
  idturma int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  codturma varchar(50),
  nomeprofessor varchar(50),
  quantidadealunos int,
  idaluno int,
  FOREIGN KEY(idaluno) REFERENCES Aluno (idaluno)
);
```

Agora vamos ao problema, não pode colocar os nomes dos campos entre `aspas simples`, então o seu `INSERT` ficaria assim:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Aluno (nomeAluno, matricula) VALUES('$NOME', '$MATRICULA')";
```

Depois desse `INSERT` você precisa recuperar o `idaluno` que foi gerado automaticamente:

```
$query = "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS id";
```

e ai sim realizar o `INSERT` nas outras tabelas:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Endereco (idendereco, nomerua, cidade, idaluno) VALUES('$NOMERUA', '$CIDADE', $IDALUNO)";
$query = "INSERT INTO Turma (codturma, nomeprofessor, quantidadealunos, idaluno VALUES ('$CODTURMA', '$NOMEPROFESSOR', $QUANTIDADE, $IDALUNO)"
```

Comment: Acredito que o usuário irá utilizar conexão mysqli e por isso para recuperar o ID será via mysqli_insert_id

Comment: correto. Estou suando Mysql

Comment: SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO @ID; ??

Comment: $id = mysqli_insert_id($query); ??